# Add a tag to a specific element within a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello everyone I would need help in order to spot specific elements within a column and add a tag to it.

So here is an exemple :

```
COL1 COL2 
G1   NC_007082.3:454361-45257(-)
G1   JANR01000149.1:21752-22322(+):Homo_erectus
G1   scaffold_187:21184-22663(+):Homo_sapiens
G2   scaffold_37957:40-526(-):Neandertalensis_fam
G2   NW_003791909.1:1499188-1499529(+)
G3   JANR010009.1_0:21752-22322(+):Canis_lupus
```

and I would like to add `:New_species` to all `COL2` without `:Content1_content2` at the end.

So I should then get :

```
COL1 COL2 
G1   NC_007082.3:454361-45257(-):New_species
G1   JANR01000149.1:21752-22322(+):Homo_erectus
G1   scaffold_187:21184-22663(+):Homo_sapiens
G2   scaffold_37957:40-526(-):Neandertalensis_fam
G2   NW_003791909.1:1499188-1499529(+):New_species
G3   JANR010009.1_0:21752-22322(+):Canis_lupus
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible set add new values if `COL2` ending by `)` use [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['COL2'].str.endswith(')'), 'COL2'] += ':New_species'
print (df)
  COL1                                           COL2
0   G1        NC_007082.3:454361-45257(-):New_species
1   G1     JANR01000149.1:21752-22322(+):Homo_erectus
2   G1       scaffold_187:21184-22663(+):Homo_sapiens
3   G2   scaffold_37957:40-526(-):Neandertalensis_fam
4   G2  NW_003791909.1:1499188-1499529(+):New_species
5   G3      JANR010009.1_0:21752-22322(+):Canis_lupus
```

If possible test by `(-)` and `(+)`:

```
df.loc[df['COL2'].str.endswith(('(-)', '(+)')), 'COL2'] += ':New_species'
```